# Code First Primary key auto increment with a prefix

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a database issue. well im not sure exactly what to do. Im using the codefirst approach in an mvc5 project. 
Currently my primary keys for my tables are auto generated and they increase. eg. customerid - 0,1,2,3 etc.

I want to know, how do i add a prefix to this id, eg i want it to be Cust0 instead of just 0.

Comment: I don't think any db engine supports that feature. Basically auto identity is just for convenient in which you don't really care about the identity (it won't be used such as for searching, ...). That identity is also normally hidden from user and never shown up. If you want to show the identity then you can also append the prefix yourself. If user enters the identity you can then strip the prefix to get the actual identity before looking up.

Comment: okay, i understand. Thank you so much friend! that helps alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is what is the reason you want to have this kind of "key"? You can auto generate ID for your customer and create your own property:

```
public class Customer
{
   public const string CustomerPrefix = "Cust";

   [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}

   [NotMapped]
   public string CustomerId 
   {
      get { return string.Concat(CustomerPrefix, Id)}
   }
}
```

Btw.: It is really bad practice to have PK as a string (because of performance)

Comment: i was going to use the id as a reference number for an invoice (im doing a loan application system). thank you, this answers my question fully friend!